# Using alternate DataSource column if empty

Tags: javascript, datatable, yui

I'm using YUI2 databases. I have my columns specified like so:

var columns = [

```
{ key: "check"
            , label: '<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" id="checkAll"/>'
            , formatter: "checkbox"
            }
, { key:"subject"
            , sortable:false
            , resizeable:false
            , formatter: YAHOO.widget.DataTable.formatSubject
            , width: "16px"
            } .....more
```

Datasource:

```
var mySource = new DataSource('.do?');
    mySource.responseType   = DataSource.TYPE_JSON;
    mySource.responseSchema = {
        resultsList : 'records',
        fields      : [
            'pos'
            ,'subject'
            ,'subject2' ....
```

In my datasource I return 'subject' for each row along with another column, lets call it 'subject2'. I want the 'subject' column to use 'subject2' from the datasource when the 'subject' column for that specified row is blank. Is this possible without overwordly hacks?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I think is to just use a formatter:

```
YAHOO.widget.DataTable.formatFrom = function ( elCell, oRecord, oColumn, oData ) {
    var val = oData;
    if(val === "") {
        val = oRecord.getData().subject2;
    }....
```